# If, Then do cell formula assitance

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I am trying to get a cell to check the % of another cell. If the cell is between a % range it will display a specific number.  But I am getting the #REF! error. Any  help from the gurus..maybe even an explanation of why my formula doesn't work, would be greatly appreciated.

```
=IF(AND(H3>0%,H3<5%), "1","")(AND(H3>5.1%,H3<10%),"2","")(AND(H3>10.1%,H3<15%), "3","")(AND(H3>15.1%), "4","")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this is the formula you meant:
`=IF(AND(H3>0%,H3<5%),"1",IF(AND(H3>5.1%,H3<10%),"2",IF(AND(H3>10.1%,H3<15%), "3",IF(AND(H3>15.1%), "4","")))`

Excel doesn't support brackets after each other without any operator "`)(`".

For multiple criteria you need to nest `IF` functions as in my formula above.

Also you can use `>=` and `<=` in excel to better cover your range. In your current formula there won't be category assigned to 0, 5-5.1 ..., so even more improved formula is:
`=IF(AND(H3>=0%,H3<=5%),"1",IF(AND(H3>5%,H3<=10%),"2",IF(AND(H3>10%,H3<=15%), "3",IF(AND(H3>15%), "4","")))`

Even more optimization: if you've already test small values, then it isn't necessary to test lower limit again:
`=IF(H3>=0%,IF(H3<=5%),"1",IF(H3<=10%,"2",IF(H3<=15%,"3","4"))),"")`

Comment: Thank you very much for your input.  The optimized version for whatever reason, kept returning an error.  However The "more improved formula" (i worked from the bottom up), Excel liked it but offered to clean it up and this was the end result: =IF(AND(H4>=0%,H4<=5%),"1",IF(AND(H4>5%,H4<=10%),"2",IF(AND(H4>10%,H4<=15%),"3",IF(AND(H4>15%),"4",""))))   Again thank you for all your help.

Comment: @Weiant2001: If an answer solves your problem, you can click on the checkmark to accept it.  That indicates that your problem has been solved and recognizes the answer and the author's efforts.  See http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer.